# Single key shortcut to search in OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

One of my favorite options in OS X Terminal is searching through previously typed commands. I use it a lot. What I don't like about it is the shortcut, it's <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. In modern notebooks, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> is not placed to be found immediately. I would love to use single key to start searching, maybe <kbd>tab</kbd> on empty prompt could do the trick? It's useless anyway.

I'm using OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: You can add the following to your `.profile`/`.bashrc`/`.bash_profile`:

```
bind [key]:reverse-search-history
```

For example,

```
bind '`':reverse-search-history
```

to bind the backtick key (above Tab on a US keyboard) to the search history function. (Note that shift-backtick to get tilde will still work normally, and you can use `$()` in virtually every context that normally requires the backtick).

Comment: Upvoted. And how about the tab as I mentioned? Is there any way to make some shortcuts work only if prompt is empty?

Comment: By the way, I pasted this command in my `.profile` file and it doesn't work. I restarted Terminal, but nope. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RoboRobok: Maybe your `bash` reads from `.bashrc`? I can never figure out which one it is.

Comment: I put it in `.bash_profile` and now it works. Do you know the answer to my question? :)

Comment: @RoboRobok: No, unfortunately I am not sure if you can specify conditions like that to `readline`. You could shell out to a program but then it probably wouldn't be able to use the history functions.

Comment: Thank you. I will wait for some other answers and will select your one if nobody can advice on that tagb thing.

Comment: It should read from all that it finds as far as i know... but i keep pretty much everything in `.profile` myself.